# Inequality over the entropy of an integer-valued random variable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, information-theory, statistics

I stumbled upon this inequality over a course on Information Theory :

> If $Z\in\mathbb{N}​$ with finite mean, then $H(Z) \leq E(Z)\times h(\frac 1 {E(Z)})​$ where $h$ is the binary entropy function

I have been trying to prove it using the log-sum inequality :

> $ \sum_i a_i \log \frac {a_i}{b_i} \geq (\sum_i a_i) \log \frac {\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i} $ for $a_i, b_i$ non-negative numbers

Using, for example, $a_i = P(Z=i)$ and $b_i = iP(Z=i)$.
But I couldn't really get throught it.

Part of my problem with this inequality is that I don't understand it : where does this use of the binary entropy function come from ? Even the relation between entropy and the mean seems unnatural to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a pure math question.

Comment: Many questions over information theory and properties of the entropy have been answered on the exchange already, making information theory a relevant topic to this sub, isn't it ?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I agree that there's no direct computational content but I think information theory is on-topic, here. I'd say that information theory is a part of computer science, in contrast to something like probability theory, which is a part of mathematics that has (many) applications in computer science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man, that's a nasty inequality.

Anyways, given a certain expectation $E[Z]=\mu$, [it is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution) that the distribution that maximizes $H(Z)$ while keeping $E[Z]=\mu$ 
 is the the Geometric Distribution with parameter $p=1/\mu$.

Then, it is easy to check that the inequality is satisfied (in fact the equality holds).
Indeed, if $Z\sim Geo(p)$ then $E[Z]=1/p$ and $H(Z)=-\log p -\frac{1-p}{p}\log(1-p)$.
Since this distribution maximizes $H(Z)$, any other distribution with the same expectation will have a lower left-hand side, while the right-hand side won't change (since $E[Z]=\mu$ didn't change). This proves the claim.

Comment: $H(Z) \leq log(E(Z))$ is wrong : taking $P(Z=0) = P(Z=1) = 1/2$, for example.

Comment: Note I assume $1/E(Z)$ is a fraction. Otherwise, even the original equation doesn't hold ($h(2)$ is undefined). But something still bothers me, let me delete it for now and re-check it later.

Comment: Credit goes to Prof. A.L. who directed me to the geometric distribution.